# C# bind dictionary in wpf XAML

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, dictionary

Well, i want to build a multi-language system, but im having some problem to load a dictionary value inside the imagesource. When i bind the variabe to a textbox, it shows the value perfectly, but the same doesnt works for imagesource, here its my code:

```
        Dictionary<string, string> resource = new Dictionary<string, string>()
    {
        { "play_ready", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "play_ready.png" },
        { "play_click", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "play_click.png" },
        { "background", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "background.png" },
        { "exit", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "exit.png" },
        { "exit_click", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "exit_click.png" },
        { "exit_hover", "../../../Resources/exit_hover.png" }
    };

    public Dictionary<string, string> resourcesPath { get; set; }


    public MainWindow()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        DataContext = this;
        resourcesPath = resource;
        Config.Setup(this.configUrl);
        this.client = new Client();            
    }
```

and i have that in the XAML

```
<Trigger Property="IsMouseOver" Value="True">
                            <Setter Property="Background" TargetName="border">
                                <Setter.Value>
                                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="{Binding resourcesPath[exit_hover]}"/>
                                </Setter.Value>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A VisualBrush/ImageBrush is not part of the element tree so it doesn't inherit the DataContext.

Try this please:

```
<Window ...
    x:Name="window">
    <Window.Resources>
        <Image x:Key="img" Source="{Binding resourcesPath[exit_hover], Source={x:Reference window}}"/>
    </Window.Resources>
...
      <Setter Property="Background">
                    <Setter.Value>
                        <VisualBrush Visual="{StaticResource img}" />
                        <!-- or use ImageBrush like this. -->
                    </Setter.Value>
      </Setter>
```

In xaml.cs

```
Dictionary<string, string> resource;
public Dictionary<string, string> resourcesPath { 
    get{  if(resource == null)
            { resource = new Dictionary<string, string>() {
              { "play_ready", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "play_ready.png" },
              { "play_click", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "play_click.png" },
              { "background", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "background.png" },
              { "exit", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "exit.png" },
              { "exit_click", "Resources/" + Config.Language + "exit_click.png" },
              { "exit_hover", "../../../Resources/exit_hover.png" }
             };
           }
     return resource;}
 }


public MainWindow()
{
    InitializeComponent();
    DataContext = this;
    Config.Setup(this.configUrl);
    this.client = new Client();            
}
```

Comment: Object reference not set to to an instance of an object.

Comment: Because you initialized your public value after set DataContext. You should initialize your dictionary before set DataContext. There are several way to do this, i extended my post with a suggestion.

Comment: I'm glad I could help